# Formatting Excel through Access VBA - Range Application/Object Defined Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, range

My issue occurs on the following line:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Select
```

Background: I have a process that loads a text file, splits it into numerous other tables, then brings some of those pieces together as new tables, exports them to excel, and does some formatting.

I use a 'For Each' loop to go through my access tables. When certain tables are identified some other code runs that creates new tables (code not shown). Once a new table is created is gets exported to excel and formatted. This is where the error occurs. The first loop works fine, it is on the second loop that the code goes to error when selecting the column range.

I have done some searching on this error, it looks like the cause is often how the worksheets are referenced. I have a number of tools that use this sort of process so it would be great to finally understand the cause.

Code:

```
Dim xl                           As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook                       As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet1                     As Excel.Worksheet

outputFileName = "C:\Users\UserID\Desktop\Reports\" & tblData & ".xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tbl_Report",     outputFileName, True

Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(outputFileName)
xl.Visible = True

Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

With xlSheet1
Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Worksheets(1).Range("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J1").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J1").Borders.Weight = xlThin
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Font.Size = 11
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets(1).Range("A12:F12").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
Worksheets(1).Range("A12:F12").Borders.Weight = xlThin
Worksheets(1).Range("A12:F12").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:J100").Cells.Columns.AutoFit

xl.DisplayAlerts = False

xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close

xl.DisplayAlerts = True

Set xlSheet1 = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing

End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT - @A.S.H. beat me to it...

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet

outputFileName = "C:\Users\UserID\Desktop\Reports\" & tblData & ".xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                          "tbl_Report", outputFileName, True

Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open(outputFileName)
xl.Visible = True

Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

With xlSheet1

    .Range("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    .Range("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp

    With .Range("A1:J1")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End with

    With .Range("A1:J100")
        .Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End with

    With .Range("A12:F12")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End with


End With    

xlBook.Close True 'save changes

Set xlSheet1 = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

1) avoid using select whenever you can. It fails very often, especially when the sheet is not active..

2) Use the With statement correctly:

```
With xlSheet1
   .Columns("A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft ' <~~~ you dont need select
   .Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp ' <~~~ you dont need select

   .Range("A1:J1").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
   .Range("A1:J1").Borders.Weight = xlThin
   .Range("A1:J100").Font.Name = "Calibri (Body)"
   .Range("A1:J100").Font.Size = 11
   .Range("A1:J1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   .Range("A12:F12").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
   .Range("A12:F12").Borders.Weight = xlThin
   .Range("A12:F12").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   .Range("A1:J100").Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, it is now working. So was the error caused by the SELECT?

Comment: @makéman A lot of discussions have taken place on SO about the `Select` method. There is almost *unanimity* that it has to be avoided in VBA code as much as possible, because it fails for many reasons (the most common one being that the worksheet containing the range you want to select, is not active). Moreover the code is faster when working directly on the range, without select :)

Comment: I guess that much of the code that we see using `Select` is derived somehow from the macro recorder, but even though, it is better to edit that code and remove the use of this method..

Comment: I am having a similiar problem with this line..
    RowNo = Selection.Find(What:="SummaryType", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

The error I get is Run-Time Error 91. Once again it happens on the second loop. Is the selection getting the best of me again?

Comment: I tried replacing 'Selection' with 'xlSheet.Cells'. Now I am getting a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: @makéman I cannot tell the error because I dont see where this is in your code. but as a first guess, I'd say the trouble comes from `LookIn:=xlFormulas`. Try the search by `xlValues` to verify that everything else is working ok. (I prefer the second version of course, not the one using Selection ;) )

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added in this piece after my initial question. I have the line of code inside the 'With xlSheet1'. I realized that a static range was not going to work since not all of my reports have the same number of records. So now I am trying to grab the row number where "Summary Type" appears, then use that value to set the range for formatting. 

I gave xlValues a shot but no luck. Still getting Type Mismatch. I appreciate the tip though.